# Corsa D Stuttering Accelaration with Malfunction Light flashing

Tags: engine, vauxhall, acceleration, misfire, corsa

I have a 1.2l Vauxhall Corsa D (62 plate) that has done 63K miles. A problem has developed over the last day or two that is becoming a concern, and has got worse over the last 24 hours.

Whilst accelerating in 2nd and 3rd, the car stutters and judders, losing revs and slowing slightly. This goes on for the whole journey. When it happens badly, the malfunction light flashes, and if i ease off the accelerator, it stops, but there is still a slight hesitation in the engine.

About a year ago, the coil pack was changed, the symptoms at the time were similar but nowhere near as bad, and the light never came on.

Any ideas? I've read it could be a faulty lambda sensor, or MAF.

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/16583/12030

Answer (score 4):

A flashing check engine light means you have an active misfire.  Driving your car while misfiring for an extended period of time can cause damage to your catalytic converter, so try not do do that.

Studdering/juddering or however you want to describe it is also a definite sign of a misfire.  Suspecting the coil(s) or wires is good, and that should be your first area to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hmmm.  and I was thinking dirty/blocked fuel filter.

Comment: Not saying this is the only, or right answer, but with a misfire, it makes sense to check the _fire_ part first.

Comment: Fairly certain there is no fuel filter on a Corsa D... spent a while investigating this last year.

Comment: @JPhi1618, you da man!  (I have absolutely no clue what kind of car or vintage this is.  I presume a 62 plate means its from 1962?  Sort of like a California Mustang with blank and orange license plates?)

Comment: You know actually a blocked air filter or blocked / restricted fuel flow will  propagate as failure during high acceleration.  I don't know why a spark failure would happen only during high acceleration (unless perhaps something is loose, and grounding out, etc...)

Comment: @zipzit I think a 62 plate means a 2012MY car.

Answer (score -1):

Jphil top man! My Corsa d 1.4 petrol had service 2.5yrs ago and 2 weeks later I went back as it had the occasional stutter after driving more than 20miles they said it was rubbish Tesco fuel! Ran tank down to almost empty refilled still had problem. Along the way been to several garages for other work and asked them to investigate but all came back with shrugged shoulders and no diag codes don't know where to look! Mechanics?
After reading this response researched you tube and web 're changing coil and wow how easy took it off and corroded took less time than plugging a diag code reader!!! Annoying as several "professionals" had apparently looked at it and charged me when unqualified me took less than 10mins. My Mrs made me tea whilst I opened the bonnet I had removed inspected the coil pack then changed plugs and replaced new coil pack...tea still hot enough to drink!!!
Cheers jphil

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65640)